# avoid write.table to save R's (\) in the exported .txt file

Tags: r, write.table

Considering the following string:

```
my_string <- c('this is "my_string", it uses "double-"qoutes" because"" I need them"')

write.table(my_string, "my_string.txt")
```

When I open the `my_string.txt` file the output is exactly the following:

```
"x"
"1" "this is \"my_string\", it uses \"double-\"qoutes\" because\"\" I need them\""
```

Basically it added "x" and "1" and the most annoying thing are the back-slash () present in all the file.

How can I avoid this annoying thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row.names=F`, `col.names=F` and `quote=F`

That is:

```
write.table(my_string, "my_string.txt",quote=F,row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

`?write.table`  for more options

Comment: it works. Also inside the text of my long string I have a lot of '###NEWLINE###' any idea about how to deal with them in such a way to have `my_string.txt` having actual new line?

Comment: Do you want the string to continue on the next line? Then use ```\n``` as in ```my_string <- c('this is "my_string", it uses \n "double-"qoutes" because"" I need them"')```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach I found somewhere is:

```
fileConn<-file("my_string.txt")

writeLines(my_string, fileConn)

close(fileConn)
```